# Android:: Custom url scheme not working in Samsung galaxy 10inch tablet's android's webkit browser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-browser, galaxy-tab

Custom url scheme is not working in Samsung galaxy 10inch tablet's android webkit browser. But the same is working fine in Chrome browser in the device. Want to know why this is happening? Please let me know if any one faced this kind of problem.
Browser should open the respected application and should pass intent data when user clicks on the link. The intent data will be Like `intent://#Intent;scheme=samplescheme;package=com.company.sampleapp;S.openurl=" + encodeURI(customOpenURL) + ";S.closeurl=" + encodeURI(customCloseURL) + ";end";`

This is my Manifest file,

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        android:label="@string/activity_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="samplescheme" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```